# News Feed FQL Failing, says permissions are required

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, get, facebook-fql

I have a problem when I'm trying to read the users news feed with an FQL query...

The query is constructed like this:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, type, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed')
```

My HTTP GET looks like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20post_id,%20actor_id,%20target_id,%20type,%20message,%20attachment%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20in%20(SELECT%20filter_key%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20me()%20AND%20type%20=%20'newsfeed')%20LIMIT%2010%20OFFSET%200&access_token=<User specific access token from trading "code" to access_token">
```

The user is authenticated with my app previously, and the permissions that has been granted are as follows:

[image: Permissions]

However, when executing the GET request stated above, I get this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#606) Queries for these filter_keys: \"nf\" require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 606
    }
}
```

I have double checked and the provided `access_token` is **valid** for my user account.

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Try using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ to find available permissions for the token

Comment: @SurabhilSergy The permissions are put in the "scopes" field i presume? Only one there is `user_friends`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes mostly.Here your access token is only having the 'user_friends' permission and not read_stream

Comment: @SurabhilSergy Hmm.. Did you see my picture? I thought i'd have read_stream approved with the app already?

Comment: @SurabhilSergy Oh! Do I have to send the extra permissions as a GET variable when making the call to the login page to get my "code" ?

Comment: The permission scope is by default not set on facebook's development plattform. It's usually done though the login link.